# Синхронное удаление слайдов из 2х слайдеров

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Есть 2 засинхроненых слайдера слайдера. По клику на кнопку "close-btn" первого слайда в основном слайдере хотелось бы убрать этот же номер слайда из вспомогательного слайдера. Вёрстку менять не могу. У каждого слайда есть уникальный data-slick-index, но подобраться к нему мне не хватает знаний. В js плохо разбираюсь. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой. Вот ссылка на плагин http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mainSlider').slick({
        asNavFor: '.forSlider'
    });
    $('.forSlider').slick({
        asNavFor: '.mainSlider'
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="mainSlider">
  <div class="slide1">
   <div class="close-btn"></div>
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="slide10"></div>
</div>

<div class="forSlider">
  <div class="slide1"></div>
  ...
  <div class="slide10"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Приведите код удаление слайда для первого слайдера.

Answer (score 0):

пробовал через index(), но явно не получается:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.compare-goods-list-close-btn').on('click', function() {

  var indexOfcard = $(this).index('.compare-goods-list-close-btn');
       
    $('.compare-goods-list').slick('slickRemove', $('.slick-  slide').index(indexOfcard));
   
   $('.compare-goods-fix__list').slick('slickRemove', $('.slick-slide').index(indexOfcard));
    })
  });
});
```